# In the Star Wars series how does Yoda die?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

I have been very curious about how Yoda died. All I remember is that in the last movie before they came out with the Force Awakens, Yoda is in his little pod and is talking to Han Solo (or at least I think it was Han Solo) before he gets in his pod and disappears.

Comment: Yoda never meets Han Solo. When you say "the last movie before they cane out with *The Force Awakens*, are you referring to *Revenge of the Sith* (the last one released) or *Return of the Jedi* (the last one in chronological order)?

Comment: I do not remember the name of the movie

Comment: “Old Jedi never die, they just fade away.”

Comment: Yoda and Han spend some time together in *The Padawan Menace*

Comment: yoda was a jedi so why did somebody take the jedi tag off?

Comment: never mind forget I even Asked this entire question please

Comment: This is a strange question.  Looks like you barely paid any attention while watching.  Do you also need to know who Luke's father is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yoda dies of old age in Episode VI, Return of the Jedi. This is the last movie of the original trilogy, but it was released long before the last movie made before The Force Awakens, because the story has not been released in chronological order.

Yoda is in his home in Dagobah, meeting with Luke, and dies in his own bed.

What you've seen might be something from Revenge of the Sith (which features [Yoda talking to Chewbacca before getting into a pod](https://youtu.be/ww0WFDierYg?t=16)) but chronologically takes place *before* the events of Return of the Jedi.

The clip of Yoda's death can be seen below